# How to access UITextfield placeholder in Unit Test?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

[image]

How can I access the placeholder value of a UITextfield inside XCTestCase? Currently I'm getting an error 'Ambigous use of placeholder'.

```
import XCTest
@testable import Project

class Tests: XCTestCase {

   func testExample() {
        let login = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboards.Authentication, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        let _ = login.view
        XCTAssertEqual("Email ID", login.emailTextField.placeholder)
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case everything works fine. Try to do project clean up. Could you post LoginViewController content.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type you have in `LoginViewController`.

From my understanding, you have some custom type. I guess you have the same property declared `placeholder` in your custom type.

If this is the case, you just suggest to Swift what exactly type you need.

I guess for testing you need `UITextField`.

```
    let textField = UITextField() //works fine, direct type
    XCTAssertNotNil(textField.placeholder)
    
    let typed = (login.emailTextField as? UITextField)
    XCTAssertNotNil(typed.placeholder)
```